# export nested PHP array to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like to export this structure to CSV :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 935722507
            [resource_state] => 2
            [athlete] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21061939
                    [resource_state] => 1
                )

            [name] => Moon Run
            [start_latlng] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 45.73
                    [1] => 4.82
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 935722508
            [resource_state] => 2
            [athlete] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21061939
                    [resource_state] => 1
                )

            [name] => Evening Run
            [start_latlng] => Array
            (
                [0] => 45.73
                [1] => 4.82
            )
         )    
)
```

I need a recursive method to export a file with these headers :

```
id; resource_state; athlete.id; athlete.resource_state; name; start_latlng.0; start_latlng.1...
```

Do you know a PHP library for to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to export to CSV, you need "flat" data - meaning an array with only one level off columns inside it.  So first, create an array with keys that match the CSV fields you show in your question.

Once you have the array, use the fputcsv() function in PHP to write each row to a file (note that you need to write the header line manually).

Comment: thanks, but I want something dynamic, because I don't know the number of fields, the number of nested levels...